# Is there any way to identify updated/upserted in mongoose/mongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Actually I want to know is there any way to identify updated old record or added new record after using findOneAndUpdate() with upsert: true option in mongoose/mongoDB?.

I am using

```
// partial code 

var update = {$set:fieldsToSet};
    var options = {new: true, upsert:true};
    var created = yield User.findOneAndUpdate(fieldsQuery, update, options).exec();

// here I want to check updated old record or create new record
```

Comment: You can't do both with the options `{new: true, upsert: true}` as the atomic update only returns the modified document with that operation; you may need to do a separate query to return the unmodifed doc i.e. `var original = yield User.findOne(fieldsQuery).exec();`

Comment: @chridam I used both and working however my question was is there any way to identify  updated record or created new record. thanks for your replay

Answer (score 1):

Use the built-in `timestamps` option in your schema, so you can check the `createAt` field.

```
var User = new Schema({
  ...,
  {
    timestamps: true,
});
```

This will automatically add `createdAt` and `updatedAt` fields to your schema.

---

### Applied to your code

```
const callTime = new Date();

User.findOneAndUpdate(...)
 .then((ret) => {
    // It just get created
    if (ret.createAt.getTime() >= callTime.getTime()) {}

    // It get modified
 });
```